# SQL value must bigger than other value by reach a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this

```
SELECT *
FROM tl_products 
WHERE preisbevor > preis 
ORDER BY updatetime DESC
LIMIT 25
```

It works and gets all products with preisbevor is bigger than preis. But i will only get items that have preisbevor more than 1 of preis

Now, it give us "productname preisbevor: 2.00$ and have preis: 1.99$" 
but i will only get products that have preisbevor bigger than preis and must be reach 1$

Like: "productname has preisbevor: 2.99$ and have preis: 1.99$", if it has 2.98$ i dont will have this item...

Comment: `WHERE preisbevor >= preis + 1`

Comment: omg sorry yeah thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tl_products 
WHERE preisbevor >= preis+1 
ORDER BY updatetime DESC 
LIMIT 25
```